# Is there a way to run c or c++ file without linking to -framework ApplicationServices?

Tags: c++, c, macos, opencv

Alright, so I wanted to compile my c++ file with make coz I have an opencv code in there. Now, the thing is I wanted to move or perform cursor event on Mac OS. And using this link below, I could successfully test cursor event function before integrating that code inside my c++ file:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGEventRef

So, for compilation I have to write this up on the terminal:
gcc -o hello hello.c -framework ApplicationServices

Whereas, I've got a c++ file and I just write up:
make

and my file is created for execution. If for instance I integrate the code with my c++ file I get the following error messages on the terminal:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_CFRelease", referenced from:
  _main in hello-5d977f.o
 "_CGEventCreateMouseEvent", referenced from:
  _main in hello-5d977f.o
 "_CGEventPost", referenced from:
  _main in hello-5d977f.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me on this!

Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with the cursor, but this may help... https://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the functions you're using in your program are part of the ApplicationServices framework. As a result, you need to link against that framework when compiling your application.

You can make the `make` utility link against that framework automatically by including the following in a `Makefile`:

```
LDLIBS += -framework ApplicationServices
```

Comment: Alright, so the header of: #include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h> is creating a problem with my opencv code which is showing me errors on 2 things: 1. Size  2. Point: error: reference to 'Size' is
      ambiguous
    erode(image,image,getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5,5)));    error: reference to 'Point' is
      ambiguous
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
              ^
/usr/include/MacTypes.h:542:41: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Point'
typedef struct Point                    Point;

Comment: I figured I could use cv::point or cv::Size to fix the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated problem. Ask it in a separate question.